# set lower database mysql

Tags: mysql, lowercase

Can look like a stupid question, but i don't want to mess it here

would 
`"update table SET field = LOWER(field)"` turn every field on table to lowercase? (and will do nothing, else, right?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess it BACK UP FIRST. We could be an evil bunch of trolls!

It will also cause any update trigger on the table to run.

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't handle even 5 minutes with problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from possible table locks on large tables (especially MyISAM), that should be fine.

And thats:

update table SET field = LOWER(field)

Answer (score 0):

Right. But you are working with two different fields in your query.

Answer (score 0):

This would not update every field, only the specifically named field would be converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table SET field = LOWER(field) WHERE field LIKE '%'
```

Comment: A "show all" filter is the same as having no filter, except slower.